# BootstrapTimepicker is not Working on Dynamically Generated Fields

Tags: jquery, timepicker

`BootstrapTimePicker` is not working on input field which is generated Dynamically using `jquery`.

I have generated the dynamic fields in the form using jquery in which one of the field is using bootstraptimepicker that field is not working. I don't know why. I have included the code and attached the image below.

[image: Layout Image]

```html
<div class="form-group input_fields_wrap">
  <div class="control-label col-sm-2">Booking time <span class="red">*</span></div>
  <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker col-sm-3 " style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 9px; float:left">
    <input id="ScheduledTime" type="text" name="bookingtime[]" class="form-control input-sm ScheduledTime">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="control-label col-sm-2">Booking Count <span class="red">*</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <input id="bookingcount" type="number" min="0" name="bookingcount[]" class="form-control input-sm">

  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="control-label col-sm-2"><button type="button" class="add_field_button fa fa-plus btn btn-info"></button></div>
  @*
  <div class="control-label col-sm-2"><button type="button" class="remove_field fa fa-plus btn btn-info">&times;</button></div>*@



</div>


---------- Script---------------
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
      e.preventDefault();
      if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment

        $(wrapper).append('<div><br/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><div class="control-label col-sm-2">Booking time <span class="red">*</span></div><div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker col-sm-3 " style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 9px; float:left"><input id="ScheduledTime" type="text" name="bookingtime[]" class="form-control input-sm ScheduledTime"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span></div><div class="control-label col-sm-2">Booking Count <span class="red">*</span></div><div class="col-sm-1"><input id="bookingcount" type="number" min="0" name="bookingcount[]" class="form-control input-sm"></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div>');
      }
    });

    /*Generating Dynamic Fields */
    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('div').remove();
      x--;
    })
  })
  $(".ScheduledTime").timepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried re-initialising it after you add a new field to the DOM? e.g.   
$('#my-new-dynamic-element').timepicker()

Comment: I have re-initialised the timepicker on the   $(add_button).click(function (e) {} but still it isn't working.

Comment: Yes, I missed that originally. It's because your selector is too limited. Amir's answer should work... or perhaps selecting the window/document instead of body.

Comment: I tried Amir's method and that even isn't working.

Comment: @KovidPurohit this code snippet doesn't seems to be working. can you create an independent fiddle on site like http://jsfiddle.net or codepen and share it here?

Comment: Hi, I have resolved the issue. Thanks to Amir and ProEvilz that their suggestions helped me and vibs next time whenever I'll post any question I'll use the jsfiddle to render the code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I just reinitialized the   $(".ScheduledTime").timepicker(); 
after the line that generates dynamic fields inside the button click event which is generating dynamic fields on addmore click. Thanks for the Help folks :)

```
        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();


            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                debugger;
                $(wrapper).append('<div><br/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><div class="control-label col-sm-2">Booking time <span class="red">*</span></div><div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker col-sm-3 " style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 9px; float:left"><input id="ScheduledTime" type="text" name="bookingtime[]" class="form-control input-sm ScheduledTime"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span></div><div class="control-label col-sm-2">Booking Count <span class="red">*</span></div><div class="col-sm-1"><input id="bookingcount" type="number" min="0" name="bookingcount[]" class="form-control input-sm"></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div>');

                $(".ScheduledTime").timepicker();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Then you should probably accept my first answer that I have just un-deleted. Note the commented out line... " // AFTER "

Comment: Thanks ProEvilz your suggestion helped me and I have resolved the issue.  and I should even thank Amir who tried to help me. Actually previously I reinitialised the bootstraptimepicker before the line that is generating dynamic data so initially it isn't worked but later I found the solution

Comment: running timepicker() every time after adding an element is not the solution, it's just a dirty workaround

Comment: So, Amir can you suggest me some other alternative for this

Answer (score 1):

you need to use on with the correct event and that is what you are doing wrong I assume.
assuming you have `body` as wrapper and your newly created input elements can be selected by `.bootstrap-timepicker input` , this way you can achieve what you are looking for:

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', ".bootstrap-timepicker input", function() {
        $(".bootstrap-timepicker input").timepicker();
});
```

Comment: and you should run the whole thing inside document.ready at first!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reinitialise timepicker on the newly added field.

```
//AFTER adding new field
$('#my-new-dynamic-element').timepicker()
```